# PostgreSQL absolute over relative xpath location

Tags: postgresql, xpath

Consider the following xml document that is stored in a PostgreSQL field:

```
 <E_sProcedure xmlns="http://www.minushabens.com/2008/FMSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" modelCodeScheme="Emo_ex" modelCodeSchemeVersion="01" modelCodeValue="EMO_E_PROCEDURA" modelCodeMeaning="Section" sectionID="11">
        <tCatSnVsn_Pmax modelCodeScheme="Emodinamica_referto" modelCodeSchemeVersion="01" modelCodeValue="tCat4" modelCodeMeaning="My text"><![CDATA[1]]></tCatSnVsn_Pmax>
</E_sProcedure>
```

If I run the following query I get the correct result for Line 1, while Line 2 returns nothing:

```
SELECT
--Line 1
TRIM(BOTH FROM array_to_string((xpath('//child::*[@modelCodeValue="tCat4"]/text()', t.xml_element)),'')) as tCatSnVsn_Pmax_MEANING
--Line2
,TRIM(BOTH FROM array_to_string((xpath('/tCatSnVsn_Pmax/text()', t.xml_element)),'')) as tCatSnVsn_Pmax
FROM (
    SELECT unnest(xpath('//x:E_sProcedure', s.XMLDATA::xml, ARRAY[ARRAY['x', 'http://www.minushabens.com/2008/FMSchema']])) AS xml_element
    FROM sr_data as s)t;
```

What's wrong in the xpath of Line 2?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your second xpath() doesn't return anything because of two problems. First: you need to use `//tCatSnVsn_Pmax` as the `xml_element` still starts with `<E_sProcedure>`. The path `/tCatSnVsn_Pmax` tries to select a top-level element with that name.

But even then, the second one won't return anything because of the namespace. You need to pass the same namespace definition to the xpath(), so you need something like this:

```
SELECT (xpath('/x:tCatSnVsn_Pmax/text()', t.xml_element, ARRAY[ARRAY['x', 'http://www.minushabens.com/2008/FMSchema']]))[1] as tCatSnVsn_Pmax
FROM (
    SELECT unnest(xpath('//x:E_sProcedure', s.XMLDATA::xml, ARRAY[ARRAY['x', 'http://www.minushabens.com/2008/FMSchema']])) AS xml_element
    FROM sr_data as s
)t;
```

---

With modern Postgres versions (>= 10) I prefer using `xmltable()` for anything nontrivial. It makes passing namespaces easier and accessing multiple attributes or elements.

```
SELECT xt.*
FROM sr_data
  cross join 
      xmltable(xmlnamespaces ('http://www.minushabens.com/2008/FMSchema' as x),
               '/x:E_sProcedure'
               passing (xmldata::xml)
               columns 
                  sectionid text path '@sectionID', 
                  pmax text path 'x:tCatSnVsn_Pmax',
                  model_code_value text path 'x:tCatSnVsn_Pmax/@modelCodeValue') as xt
```

For your sample XML, the above returns:

```
sectionid | pmax | model_code_value
----------+------+-----------------
11        | 1    | tCat4
```